# Does removal of a Github Release , with a tag v1.0, also removes the associated assets?

Tags: github

There is a Github release (with a tag `v1.0`) for a public `repo` associating with two assets (Auto-generated by **Github**) viz., `sourcecode.zip` and `soucecode.tar.gz`.

If `release` is deleted, then does this `delete` action also remove two assets from the repo?

Answer (score 0):

I had a release (with tag v1.0) published in **github** with two assets `Source Code(zip)` and `Source Code(tar.gz)` which were auto-generated by Github.
I did some changes to `README.md` file and wanted to include the latest `README.md` into the existing release rather than creating a new one such as v1.1.

So I logged into **github** and deleted the release and it disappeared.
I freshly created a new release with same tag `v1.0` and as usual the two assets `Source Code(zip)` and `Source Code(tar.gz)` appeared again.
I downloaded the `zip` file to my desktop and inspected the contents. To my surprise the `README.md` file among the `zip` files was older one and not the latest. I thought that I had made some mistake.
So I repeated the process. Every time I downloaded the `zip` and found out only the older `README.md` again and again.

I realized that my delete action on the release had removed it from `github` but not the two assets. This means the assets should have been associated with tag `v1.0` rather than with release.

To confirm my findings, I issued the command `git push --delete origin v1.0` from my desktop.
I visited `github` and again created the release with tag `v1.0`. I inspected `zip` file after downloading.
At last, I found out that the latest `README.md` was sitting among the `ziped` files! That was what I wanted!!

The lesson learnt was that `git` command issued from desktop not only removed the release but also the tag associated with release.
Thus, the removal of tag `v1.0` also removed the two assets associated with it.

In fact, I wanted to share this experience and so this post.